# Как сделать подсчёт того сколько раз прошли тест формата SWF?

Tags: php, javascript, html, actionscript

Есть викторина выполненная в формате SWF, есть её исходники. Как сделать так чтоб по завершению викторины(после определенного слайда) вести счетчик. Сейчас сделано с поморью php но по завершению открывается новая вкладка с пустым php. Версия actionScript 2.0

Answer (score 1):

Поставьте функцию в нужном вам слайде, которая будет отправлять данные на php скрипт. Для этого вам потребуется по крайней мере одна переменная типа LoadVars и функция sendAndLoad()

```
myVars = new LoadVars();result = new LoadVars();
myVars.userid = "345";
myVars.userresult = "9/10";
myVars.sendAndLoad("http://localhost/pagina.php", result, "POST");
```

Документация: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AS2LCR/Flash_10.0/help.html?content=00001161.html#305040